# Use Python library without installing

Tags: python

I wish to customize the popular Python library Scrapy (mostly include some `print` commands etc) to check how it works internally. I pulled the source code from GitHub and created a `conda` virtual env to begin my experiments.

First, I went into the library folder and tried `$ python -c "import scrapy"`; this asks me to download some dependency which I do using `pip` and after a few iterations, I am able to import it.

Is this usable just yet? Do I not have to compile/install it etc?

Also, Scrapy has a CLI too which I wish to use (eg `$ scrapy --help`). How should I go about that?

What I wish in the end is to edit a core file in the distribution, save it, go the my `home` directory, run Scrapy from the terminal and see what changes.

Comment: Its python, there's no "compiling."

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian That is wrong, there is compiling in Python. Python JITs your *.py-files into *.pyc. When you execute code it is instantly compiled into Python bytecode. You can compile files manually using `python -m compileall .` (the `.` means "compile everything in the current directory"). Just that Python does the compilation without you needing to do it manually does not mean there is no compiling on Python.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for CDing into the source directory and then running ``pip install -e .``, which installs the package at the current location in editable mode.

Then you should be able to edit the source and see your changes when running ``scrapy`` on the command line, given that you run it with that same virtualenv enabled.

Comment: /Sigh, @Dakkaron can always count for someone on the internet to be a language lawyer. No. Assuming we are talking about CPython, which we are, then there is no JIT. That's PyPy. The "compiling" is just bytecode, still not native code. /last word.

Comment: Doesn't matter if it compiles into native code or into byte code, it is still compiling. Same as you have to compile Java and it still ends up being byte code and not native code. It is still called compiling. Check Wikipedia for a definition of compiling. There it says that compiling means translating from one programming/machine language into another. So it is still called compiling even if you compile C++ into JavaScript. You can always count on someone correcting your wrong statements on SO, because that's what you have a community for.

Comment: Is it possible for you to install system dependencies, e.g. deb packages on the system you are working on?

Comment: Yes, that is possible. I install Scrapy's dependencies using `pip` till I can import it

Answer (score 0):

While there is compiling in Python (contrary to Edgar Aroutiounian's comment) it is not necessary, since Python has a Just-In-Time-Compiler that compiles all the scripts when you execute them.
If you can import the file you can usually use it.

Comment: What about the command line usage ? How do I go about using them without installing ?

Comment: Also, there are some Python modules that interface with C libraries and require compiling of the C code bits when building from source.

Comment: If you don't install the library properly, you need to put it into the path of your project to import it. If you are in the right directory you can use it from the command line.

Comment: I did add it to the `sys.path` permanently. So, I can import from anywhere. But I do not understand how I could use the command line arguments.

Comment: @HellmarBecker, luckily Scrapy doesn't have them. Otherwise the problem would have become so much more difficult !

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you build and install, but in a sandboxed environment.

I believe the easiest way for you to modify scrapy and use the modified version, while keeping turnaround time down, is to do

```
python setup.py install
```

in the root of the git repository.

If you want to avoid installing the modified scrapy on your system you could use `virtualenv` to create a sort of sandbox well suited for python projects.

Typically you'd install the virtualenv package, on debian it's `python-virtualenv`, and then do:

```
mkdir ~/envs
virtualenv ~/envs/scrapy
source ~/envs/scrapy/bin/activate
```

which gives you an environment where the step `python setup.py install` would only install your modified scrapy in the `~/envs/scrapy/` directory. This will leave your system unaffected by your installation.

This environment is active independent of in what directory you are working in. To exit the virtualenv you just write `deactivate` and you're back to you normal environment.

Scrapy does however have dependencies for its build so you'll need those on your system when installing in this manner. If this is an issue, you could take this further and use an instance of `lxc` with e.g. an Ubuntu template to get a sandbox for the complete system.

Comment: I really wasn't eager to install every time I make a small change. As a temporary fix, I am `cd`ing into the Scrapy repo and importing from there. This way, I get the changes I made. The only drawback is that I have to use Scrapy from scripts; and not via cli (eg. `$ scrapy list`)

Comment: I see. And yeah that's what you explicitly said in your question :) The turnaround is pretty short when re-installing after the first time though.

Comment: Ah, I did not know about that. Shall try. I wish virtualenv would create separate bash config files too, then I could point bash to the scrapy repo and things would get fine. `lxc` can be of use here, thanks for the tip.

Comment: If you install your modified code in the virtual environment then you will be able to call the installed scrapy and use the cli and everything. At that point the repo is not currently relevant.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. Maybe I will settle for installation after my changes.